# Vue Quassar Standalone example not working

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying a simple standalone vue/quasar example by copy pasting all code from code pen into a single html file,
but its not working.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.12.13/dist/quasar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">                    
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.12.13/dist/quasar.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="q-app">
    <div class="q-pa-md q-gutter-sm">
      <q-btn style="background: #FF0080; color: white" label="Fuchsia"></q-btn>
      <q-btn flat style="color: #FF0080" label="Fuchsia Flat"></q-btn>
      <q-btn style="background: goldenrod; color: white" label="Goldenrod"></q-btn>
      <q-btn outline style="color: goldenrod;" label="Goldenrod"></q-btn>
      <q-btn color="grey-4" text-color="purple" glossy unelevated icon="camera_enhance" label="Purple text"></q-btn>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#q-app'
  });
</script>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Your given example is working ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fquasar.dev%2Fvue-components%2Fbutton , this one i followed

Comment: add the .js links in index.html at the end of `body` tag, after `<div id="q-app"></div>`

Comment: @IgorMoraru it worked thanks, but why it required after body  ?

Comment: @Chanky it's common practice to put javascript files at the bottom of body tag, because almost every js script relies on DOM being fully loaded to function properly. if you put them in `<head>` tag, it will load before the DOM is ready, and this is prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here its working!

Head tag loads all style and script before Body and its HTML and QUASSAR or any other stand alone library which need to put application/plugin into a HTML element that must load after Body because.

Body and its element loads before script so script will be able to access those Html.

Here in your case the QUASSAR script needs   to boot app inside that

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.12.13/dist/quasar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">                    
</head>
<body>
  <div id="q-app">
    <div class="q-pa-md q-gutter-sm">
      <q-btn style="background: #FF0080; color: white" label="Fuchsia"></q-btn>
      <q-btn flat style="color: #FF0080" label="Fuchsia Flat"></q-btn>
      <q-btn style="background: goldenrod; color: white" label="Goldenrod"></q-btn>
      <q-btn outline style="color: goldenrod;" label="Goldenrod"></q-btn>
      <q-btn color="grey-4" text-color="purple" glossy unelevated icon="camera_enhance" label="Purple text"></q-btn>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.12.13/dist/quasar.umd.js"></script>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#q-app'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```